# Is there a function to get cursor position within an element no matter what the padding/margin is on it or its parents?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

Do any of the browsers provide this directly? or may be through one of the libraries?

All I could find was some examples of how to iterate through the hierarchy to add up all the margins and paddings. Is that the only way?

Comment: Are you looking to find the X,Y coordinates of the mouse pointer?

Comment: Yes, within a container such as a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers provide some pointer-related properties of an event object, allowing you determine the X,Y coordinates of the mouse pointer for events such as clicking a button or moving the mouse.

Of such properties, you are likely to find one relative to the [event's target](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target), although this may depend on the browser and may not be consistent across different browser vendors.

Use [jQuery's mouse position features](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) to abstract away differences between browsers.

Answer (score 0):

ScreenX/ScreenY has the correct cursor position [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ogabi3/2)

Properties documented here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position